# Universal binary framework, ..../TestTarget have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compilation, xcode12

I try create binary universal framework, with next steps

```
mkdir build

xcodebuild clean build \
  -project Target/TestTarget.xcodeproj \
  -scheme TestTarget \
  -configuration Release \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -derivedDataPath derived_data
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

mkdir build/simulator

cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TestTarget.framework build/simulator

xcodebuild clean build \
  -project Target/TestTarget.xcodeproj \
  -scheme TestTarget \
  -configuration Release \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -derivedDataPath derived_data
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES


mkdir build/devices

cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TestTarget.framework build/devices

mkdir build/universal

cp -r build/devices/TestTarget.framework build/universal/

lipo -create \
  build/simulator/TestTarget.framework/TestTarget \
  build/devices/TestTarget.framework/TestTarget \
  -output build/universal/TestTarget.framework/TestTarget
  
cp build/simulator/TestTarget.framework/Modules/TestTarget.swiftmodule/* build/universal/TestTarget.framework/Modules/TestTarget.swiftmodule
```

but have **ERROR**
..../TestTarget have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file

Answer (score 0):

As Apple support described [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669411?answerId=652663022#652663022)

> Scripts like that -- anything that tries to manipulate the output with commands like lipo -- still produces an unsupported configuration in the binary.

And the way to go is distribute the `framework` as a `xcframework`. [Here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev544efab96) you have Apple docs how to do that.

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework <path> [-framework <path>...] -output <path>
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library <path> [-headers <path>] [-library <path> [-headers <path>]...] -output <path>
```